# Duplicate entry check

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand how MSQL's Duplicate Entry works.

What I do understand is when saving

```
title='aaaaaccccc'
```

twice and the title field is unique you will get the error: Duplicate entry.

Does MySQL truncates a string with length = 200 to 64 chars and then check if the 64 chars long string is unique?

**UPDATE:**

When I save 2 records (titles) MySQL complains about violation of a unique constraint when saving the second title. The titles are the same for the first, lets say, 100 chars. After that it differs. Wy does MySQL throws a duplicate key error anyway.

Comment: What will be the point of truncating ? It can comapare full strings against each other. I dont know the exact algorithm.

Comment: You mean, if the entire length were taken into account, the title being inserted would have been unique and yet MySQL complained about violation of a unique constraint when you tried to save the value? Could your provide the definition of the unique constraint?

Comment: Yes, MySQL complains about violation of a unique constraint when saving the second title. The titles are the same for the first, lets say, 100 chars. After that it differs. Wy does MySQL throws a duplicate key error anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the data type: `varchar` columns will be trimmed, but `char` columns not (they are padded out to the specified column length).

Comment: I'm using django with Charfield(varchar) + maxlength=255